# Change axis direction

Tags: r, axis, direction, ggvis

How to change axis direction in ggvis plot?

For example, y-axis. I want an origin to be on left top of the graph (I already put my x-axis to the top by putting orient ="top").

```
data %>% 
  ggvis(~XX, ~YY) %>% 
  layer_points() %>% 
  add_axis("y", title = "Y title") %>% 
  add_axis("x", title = "X title", orient ="top")
```

Comment: Please share some code to illustrate what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want my y-axis to start at the left top and increase to the bottom (basically, to change y-axis direction) 
  `data %>% ggvis(~XX, ~YY) %>% 
  layer_points() %>%   
  add_axis("y", title = "Y title")%>%
  add_axis("x", title = "X title",
           orient ="top")`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need the `scale_numeric` argument with `reverse = TRUE` to flip the order of the range.

Below is an example based on the `mtcars` dataset.

```
library(ggvis)
mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  add_axis("x", orient = "top") %>%
  scale_numeric("y", reverse = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: No problem, and welcome to SO! Please make sure to post [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) questions in the future, that makes it easier for others to help you.